# webpack encore dev-server not found /

Tags: symfony, webpack-dev-server, webpack-encore

Hello 
 Am trying to run dev server using webpack encore by typing `npm run dev-server`, when 
checking the localhost:9000 is render me `Cannot GET /` and give that log

```
 ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:9000/ 
 ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from http://localhost:9000/build/
 ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from D:\xampp\htdocs\api-platform\public
 ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html
```

knowing I already change package.json

```
"scripts": {
"dev-server": "encore dev-server --port 9000 --disable-host-check",
"dev": "encore dev",
"watch": "encore dev --watch",
"build": "encore production --progress"
},
```

and also take look on doc 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/dev-server.html

```
Project structure
api-platform/node_modules
api-platform/public/build/entrypoints.json
api-platform/public/build/manifest.json
api-platform/package.json
api-platform/webpack.config.json
```

Controller

```
    /**
 * @Route("/", name="app")
 */
public function index()
{
    return $this->render('app/index.html.twig', []);
}
```

Comment: could you please share your project structure?

Comment: sure ill update it within  the post.

Answer (score -1):

Finally am resolving that's by subscribing a few steps.

1. Go to `package.json` and add port, disable-host-check to your dev-server:

   > "dev-server": "encore dev-server --port 9000 --disable-host-check",
2. Go to the host of your app(not of dev-server) and be sure to no have the same port between apache and dev-server.
   Cheers!